# How to set global struct property to automatically displayed as camelCase

Tags: go, go-gorm

I just newly migrated my Go project to use GORM, and I want to set a global configuration for model struct to automatically use camelCase as the json data.

job.go

```
type Job struct {
    ID uint
    Title string
    JobContent string `json:"jobContent"`
}

var data Job
db.First(&data)
```

JSON result will be:

```json
{
    "ID": 1,
    "Title": "some title",
    "jobContent": "this is a content"
}
```

// I want to automatically set all json result as camelCase,
// without manually specifying in all struct properties:

Expected Output:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "some title",
    "jobContent": "this is a content"
}
```

It is a little troublesome to set the json field for all struct properties, I'm wondering how can I set globally to automatically display json data as camelCase?

Comment: *"how can I set globally to automatically display json data as camelCase?"* -- You can't, at least not while using `encoding/json`. For structs, by default, the fields' names are used in JSON when marshaling. To change that default behaviour you have to use the tags.

Comment: @mkopriva is there a way to set the default tags (unless specified), for all struct to its property but with camelCase?

Comment: There is nothing like that, that I know of, provided by the `go` tool. If you wanted to, you could write a code generator for that though.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258546/default-case-option-for-go-json-marshal