# JSON number gets cut off after unmarshaling to interface

Tags: json, go, precision

So I have a JSON with many fields and I am looping through it as suggested by
[How effectively to change JSON keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893640/how-effectively-to-change-json-keys)
to delete some of the keys I don't need. But after deletion, the original values of the existing JSON was changed, some of them are float numbers it seems and I made a demo to show it.

How can I change this behavior? Is the `interface{}` causing the issue? Why is `1684366653200744506` cut off to `1684366653200744400`?

Thanks!

https://go.dev/play/p/X2auWqWB2fL

For reference, the output JSON is changed to 1684366653200744400

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 1684366653200744448.000000
2009/11/10 23:00:00 map[timestamp:1.6843666532007444e+18]
2009/11/10 23:00:00 json Marshal from maps of key string and value interface to batch json for insert to DB
2009/11/10 23:00:00 {"timestamp":1684366653200744400}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because by default, the `encoding/json` package stores `float64` in the interface value for JSON numbers. See [json.Unmarshal](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal):

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:
>
> - bool, for JSON booleans
> - **float64, for JSON numbers**
> - ...

You can create a decoder and call [(*Decoder).UseNumber](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Decoder.UseNumber) to change the behavior:

```golang
jsonBatch := `{"timestamp":1684366653200744506, "todelete":"string value or boolean value"}`
dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonBatch))
dec.UseNumber()
var i interface{}
if err := dec.Decode(&i); err != nil {
```

See https://go.dev/play/p/ZjWB-NfiEQL.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating a type and removing the field you don't need.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type A struct {
    Timestamp int64 `json:"timestamp"`
}

func main() {
    jsonBatch := `{"timestamp":1684366653200744506, "todelete":"string value or boolean value"}`
    i := A{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonBatch), &i); err != nil {
        log.Println("json UnMarshal from batch json failed")
        log.Println(err)
    }
    dbJsonBatch, err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("json Marshal from batch json failed")
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Println("json Marshal from maps of key string and value interface to batch json for insert to DB")
    log.Println(string(dbJsonBatch))
}
```

This prints

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 json Marshal from maps of key string and value interface to batch json for insert to DB
2009/11/10 23:00:00 {"timestamp":1684366653200744506}
```

Comment: yeah, I actually get the json from Marshaling a existing struct but needs to remove a few fields conditionally, so I converted it to a map and then delete few keys to avoid recreating a similar struct just without the fields I don't need. I am trying to delete fields within different if conditions, it seems like I need a different struct within each if statement to unmarshal the json to?